# ORA-00936: missing expression for select inner query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

this is my code:
I am using oracle 10g

```
select distinct s1.SSN, s1.S_NAME, s2.SSN, s2.S_NAME
from student s1, student s2, transcript t1
where s1.SSN <> s2.SSN AND
t1.Student_SSN = s1.SSN AND
t1.Grade = 'A' AND 
(select * from transcript t2 where 
t2.Student_SSN = s2.SSN AND t2.Grade='A');
```

I am getting this error :

> t2.Student_SSN = s2.SSN AND t2.Grade='A')  * ERROR at line 7:
>   ORA-00936: missing expression

what is the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lingering `select *` subquery in the `where` clause.  But, you should learn proper SQL syntax and explicit joins.  Presumably, you intend something like:

```
select distinct s1.SSN, s1.S_NAME, s2.SSN, s2.S_NAME
from student s1 join
     student s2
     on s1.SSN <> s2.SSN join
     transcript t1
     on t1.Student_SSN = s1.SSN AND
where t1.Grade = 'A' AND 
      exists (select 1
              from transcript t2
              where t2.Student_SSN = s2.SSN AND t2.Grade = 'A'
             );
```

I'm not sure if this does exactly what you want (which the question does not describe).  But this should fix the Oracle error.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the following. You appear to be trying to find students who both have at least one 'A' grade on their transcripts. Using `EXISTS` gets rid of the need to use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT s1.SSN, s1.s_name, s2.SSN, s2.s_name
  FROM student s1 INNER JOIN student s2
    ON s1.SSN < s2.SSN
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM transcript t1
                 WHERE t1.student_SSN = s1.SSN
                   AND t1.grade = 'A' )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM transcript t2
                 WHERE t2.student_SSN = s2.SSN
                   AND t2.grade = 'A' );
```

The reason I used `<` instead of `<>` when comparing the two values of `SSN` is that using `<>` will return rows with duplicates -- that is, a given value of `SSN` could appear twice, once for student #1 and once for student #2.